# How to logout user if idle

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, session

How do you logout a user from SharePoint if there is no user action or screen remains idle for long time, or is there a way to end user session and redirect him to login page?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the time out for your web applications in Central Admin.

Go to **Application management** > **Manage web applications**, mark one web application and select **General settings** from the ribbon.

Scroll down to "Web Page Security Validation"

This is the amount of a time a user can be idle, if they try to access the site again after the time has passed, there will be a security prompt. The default is 30 minutes.

[Configure settings for a Web application](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262107%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: Here it says `Security validations expire after a configurable amount of time, requiring the user to retry his operation` i just want to confirm does it logs out the user or displays something like try again

Comment: It closes the connections to SharePoint, requiring the user to refresh the site. It depends on your browser settings. If the users never need to enter their credentials ( Automatic Logon with current username and password ) then they won't notice anything. If they need to log into SharePoint every time they are trying to access a site, they will need to enter their credentials again.

Comment: I need to implement this for FBA

Comment: I don't think this works different for FBA. That would be if you are using any custom authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Use a JavaScript in your masterpage which redirects a user after a set interval to the SignOut.aspx page in SharePoint:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    idleTime = 0;
    LogOutInactive();
});

function LogOutInactive() {
    var idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, 60000);
    $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
    idleTime = 0;
});

$(this).keypress(function (e) {
        idleTime = 0;
    });
}

function timerIncrement() {
    idleTime = idleTime + 1;
    if (idleTime > 9) {
        window.location = "http://[your site]/_layouts/15/SignOut.aspx";
    }
}
```

Comment: What if user hits back button in browser he will be redirected to that page, i want to avoid this too

Comment: You could add this:
<script type="text/javascript">window.history.forward();function noBack(){window.history.forward();}</script>
But that will prevent using back on every page, adding an if() which checks the current url can prevent that, but I would not recommend disabling the back button. You could of course write your own custom signout.aspx which in turn redirects the users to any page you like.

Comment: security is my main concern, so i want something reliable

Comment: Once a user is logged out he will not be automatically logged in again by pushing the back button so I don't see any security vulnerabilities here.